# Slow retrieving of data even using DESC LIMIT and adding index to columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have 25,000 entries in my table and when I retrieve data from my table.. it almost take 30 secs or 1 min. I tried using DESC LIMIT and added index to my column but still doesn't work. How can I get my data in a faster way?

**this is my table_structure**

```
id (int 255)
date_sourced (date)
sha1 (varchar 255)
vsdtt (varchar 255)
trendx (varchar 255)
notes (varchar 255)
```

My desc limit is like this, user can Input how many values can be displayed

[image]

**Here is my query:**

```
$rpp = 10;
$page = 1;
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "jeremy_db");
$query_count = " SELECT * FROM jeremy_table_trend ORDER by date_sourced desc ";
$result_count = mysqli_query($conn, $query_count);
$total = mysqli_num_rows($result_count);
$temp = ($page-1)*$rpp;
$query = " SELECT * FROM jeremy_table_trend ORDER by date_sourced desc LIMIT $rpp ";
$page_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

**Then my table to display the values from db:**

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($page_result)) { $currsamp_id = $row['id'];?>
   <tr>
     <td><input class="ui checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check_box" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"></td>
     <td onclick="$('#options_<?php echo $currsamp_id ?>').dropdown('show')" style="overflow: visible !important;"> </td>
          <div class="ui dropdown item" id="options_<?php echo $currsamp_id ?>">
            <i class="settings icon"></i><i class="dropdown icon"></i>
          </div>
     <td nowrap title="Date Sourced"><?php echo $row['date_sourced'] </td>
     <td nowrap title="SHA-1"><?php echo $row['sha1'] ?></td>
     <td nowrap title="VSDT"><?php echo $row['vsdt'] ?></td>
     <td nowrap title="TrendX"><?php echo $row['trendx'] ?></td>
     <td nowrap title="Notes"><?php echo $row['notes'] ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: One possibility - Do read: [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/2469308)

Comment: My first suggestion will be, as you don't have any `where` clause in your query, try to ORDER BY `id` instead of  `date_sourced` in your first query (you will use `$total` for pagination, right?). and is your date_sourced indexed? Is all of the `date_sourced` same?

Comment: Try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jeremy_table_trend` as your first query to get total rows.

Comment: yes im using pagination, and my date_sourced is indexed, I need my table to be ordered by date_sourced

Comment: But you don't need to order by a date column to get total count. Use `COUNT(*)` instead. It will improve your first query.

Comment: yes i tried that, it lessen the loading time but still loads 30sec - 40 secs

Comment: Can you check both of the query loading time separately? And please provide how you indexed the table columns.

Comment: `id (int 255)` why is this column integer should have `255`? how big is your id actually? I think `11` will be good enough.

Comment: `select count(*) FROM jeremy_table_trend` on an indexed table (and for 25k rows, maybe even without) should take about 0.05s (in contrast to transfering 25MB to do a single `mysqli_num_rows` with that), `select ... limit 10` with a proper index should not take more than 1s either. You are either missing information (maybe the table is a view, you didn't index correctly, $rpp >> 10,  ...) or the bottleneck isn't the queries. As Ataur suggested, please run and time your queries separately on e.g. phpmyadmin, and also add both explain plans (the output of `explain select ...`) to your question.